# Update in dictionary is overwriting the key value pair in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary such that it consists another key,value pair.
while using update method in dictionary it is overwriting the old key,value pair.

```
import yaml

d1={}
l1=[]
d2={}

with open("testspec.yaml","r") as stream:
    d1.update(yaml.load(stream))

l1=d1['TestSpec'].keys()
print(l1)
for i in l1:
    #d2[i]='None'
    for key,value in d1['TestSpec'][i].items():
        if "STEP" in key:
            d2.update({i : {key :value}})      
            #print(d1['TestSpec'][i])
        else:
            del d1['TestSpec'][i][key]
#print(d1)
print(d2)
```

output of l1/print(l1):

> ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

final output/print(d2) :

> {'A1': {'STEP_8': 'A1_08'}, 'A2': {'STEP_12': 'A2_12'}, 'A3': {'STEP_34': 'A3_34'}, 'A4': {'STEP_8': 'A4_08'}}

the for loop which is returning the key,value pair from d1['TestSpec'][i].items() are such as `STEP_1 : A1_1 STEP_2 : A1_2`
so on...

Expected output:

> {'A1': {'STEP_1': 'A1_1','STEP_2': 'A1_2','STEP_3': 'A1_3'},} like this for all A2,A3,A4 also.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. We don't have access to your input `yaml` file, so please give a complete input example.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, method `update()` **LITERALLY** updates the value of the key. If you want to append another value to existing value that corresponds the key, I would recommend updating the value with `old value + new value`

Let me know if this answer works for you, or I am wrong about some point.

Comment: i didn't understand the old value and new value concept can you please explain it more briefly. thanks for your help.

Comment: For each key, you are storing an array. When you update the value of the of the key, update function stores only the new value of the key and deletes the old ones. lets say your "A1" key stores the array {"1", "2"} when you update A1 with the value 3, your "A1" key stores the value {"3"} only.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to add to the existing dictionary returned from the relevant keys.

Replace your `.update()` line with this:

```
d2[i][key] = value
```

Simply put, you wanted to append to the dictionary returned, not overwrite it with another key/value pair.

Comment: thanks for the help but i tried this way then i got a keyerror: 'A1'